# "No tests were found" for Android Studio

Tags: android, testing, android-gradle-plugin

I'm just migrated from Eclipse. My project keeps the old structure like below

```
projRoot\
    src\
    res\
    ...
    AndroidManifest.xml
    tests
    build.gradle
```

Here's content of build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests/src')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        testApplicationId 'com.xxx.yyy.test'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner'
        testHandleProfiling true
        testFunctionalTest true
    }
}
```

I'm on Android Studio 0.8 beta, Gradle 1.12, I tried every possible solution found all over SO and google without any success.

Anyone can help out? Thanks.

In addition, where can I know the current version of Android Gradle plugin?

Comment: @TacB0sS, solved, test root was set wrong

Answer (score 0):

For test source set structure, follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#test_types_and_location). It is mentioned that test source sets should be setup as follows:

- for local unit tests: module-name/src/test/java/
- for android instrumentation tests: module-name/src/androidTest/java/

In case it's still doesn't work. Android Studio may encounter sometimes issues with the recognition of the tests. And the workaround would be to run local tests by using the command line:

```
./gradlew testVariantNameUnitTest
```

Once the command is run. You can go back to Android Studio and run the tests and it should work. You can find more on running tests using command line on this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html).

Hope this helps.